# How to Remove the uploaded file from RadAsyncUpload control in web page but not from the temp folder

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to remove the uploaded files from the radasyncupload control in the web page,but not from the temp folder I have used the following code to remove it from uploaded files array.

```js
                    Array.removeAt(fileUploadObject._uploadedFiles, 0);                
                    fileUploadObject.updateClientState();
```

but the uploaded file is still showing in web page it is not removing.If I call deleteFileInputAt method then it is removing the file from the web page but it is also removing the file from the temp folder.

```js
                    fileUploadObject.deleteFileInputAt(0);
                    fileUploadObject.updateClientState();
```

How can i remove the attached file from only the control but not from the temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to manipulate the server, you can manipulate the rendered HTML. Here is an example that does the following:

- finds successful uploads through a CSS class
- gets the second one (hence the hardcoded index 1)
- removes its parent li element because all these rows render as li elements with some more HTML inside

Of course you can clean it up, refactor it and add some logic (e.g., check the innerHTML of the .ruUploadSuccess element so you know which file name you are dealing with)

```
        <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RAU1"></telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="remove a file" OnClientClick="removeAFile(); return false;" runat="server" />
        <script>
            function removeAFile() {
                var rau = $find("<%=RAU1.ClientID%>");
                var secondUploadedFileRow = $telerik.$(".ruUploadSuccess", rau.get_element())[1];
                $telerik.$(secondUploadedFileRow).closest("li").remove();
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Above code is completely removing the RadAsyncUploadListContainer  that's why not able to get the upload control back to its previous state,not able to upload any more images.

Comment: No, it doesn't: http://screencast.com/t/nOSqENSYd. Make sure you are using the latest version and review the script and the rendered HTML to see what it actually tries to do so you can emulate it.